# ENOTFOUND' to determine project ID: Error making request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND metadata.google.internal

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, nestjs, vuejs3

```
`FirebaseAppError: Failed to determine project ID: Error while making request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND metadata.google.internal. Error code: ENOTFOUND
    at D:\GIles-NMCT\Documents\3MCT\Advanced Full Stack\AFSWD_museum\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\app\credential-internal.js:192:19
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at FirebaseAuthStrategy.authorize (D:\GIles-NMCT\Documents\3MCT\Advanced Full Stack\AFSWD_museum\api\src\auth\firebase.strategy.ts:45:14)
    at FirebaseAuthStrategy.validate (D:\GIles-NMCT\Documents\3MCT\Advanced Full Stack\AFSWD_museum\api\src\auth\firebase.strategy.ts:33:21) {`
```

I can no longer see the orders linked to a particular account (from firebase) because I keep getting the error from the picture
https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0fra.png
How can I fix this error?

This is the firebase.strategy.ts file to which the error refers
https://srcshare.io/64340962c8b1aec3f69d5ac5

Comment: The error indicates an invalid credential. Have you checked that you're authenticating your request properly? Also don't post pictures of code/errors; copy paste their contents into a code block in your question.

Comment: Well, my code worked without any problems, but suddenly I got that error. And I don't know what I'm doing wrong. :(

Comment: The question stands. Have you checked that you're authenticating your request properly? Also instead of deleting the picture of the error, please copy-paste its text into your question: it included information that is not present in your code block.

Comment: Is it more clear now?

Answer (score 0):

When I encountered this error, it was because I wasn't setting the credentials environment variable (GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS) prior to the Firebase client app being initialized.

The client couldn't find the credentials during initialization, so wasn't able to make any requests.